# Analytics not fetching Wordpress.com Readers traffic

Tags: wordpress, google-analytics, blogger, web-testing, jetpack

There is a provision inside Wordpress.com dashboard called "Readers". My Jetpack is showing traffic coming from "Readers", but Site Kit is not displaying "Readers" traffic.

I want Wordpress.com readers traffic reflected in Google analytics.